# C# - WPF responsive design for different resolutions

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I´m designing an desktop app in WPF. My problem is the resolution, the minimum resolution that can support the app is 1024x768(for crt monitors) and in this resolution maximizing the app seems okay and good, but when i try the app in higher resolution then the gap between my components and their size according to resolution seems very very awful and unprofessional specially in very high resolution the empty space which make it more worst and ugly. please suggest me some easy fast guide or documentation  please.... thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: SO is the wrong place for tutorial or guideline suggestions. And without any code/xaml and screenshots we can't help you.

Comment: please check my new edit

Comment: your design is really free spirited ;) Use some Grids to line up all your fields in different rows and columns. Don't set the Width to your fields, the layout itself should do that, then they will be auto resized when the window is resized. You should also check the link that @Johanna provided, its a good starting point.

Comment: thank you @Rabban .. i did that in a test project and works for me ... actually now i have a question ... in case of eg:TextBox when the size increases its font size remains same ... is there any suggestion for this issue in such a way that also the font size increases accordingly...thank you

Comment: Do you really need to increase the font size? It's normal behavior that font size didn't increase. You can set a `MinWidth` to your `ColumnDefinition` so that the will don't decrease to invisibility. If this is a real issue for you, please create a new Question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing your WPF application, it's advisable to use one of the predefined layouts such as stacklayout, grid, dock panel etc. as these tend to be more responsive than defining the your own static layout.

Check the link below on how you can use these layouts.
https://wpftutorial.net/layoutproperties.html